# Exporting shell variables output of this code

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

so basically i have a shell script below and i wanted to know what the value of x is after the code has been executed. What does the export does in shell scripting?

```
export x=4
bash
echo $x
x=100
echo $x
exit
echo $x
```

Comment: What did you find when you googled the question?

Comment: hi sir, you cant give google lines of code. i wanted to know the output of x too

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: "*i wanted to know what the value of x is after the code has been executed*" - you can see the value, it is echoed at the end.  Did you try running this?  Why not?  Did you try `help export`?

Answer (score -1):

In theory echo will say [in order]:

```
4
100
```

then the script exits, but from the terminal you could enter the last echo manually and it would say

```
4
```

"export", from what i'm gathering is like the windows environmental variables...

```
user@machine~$export
declare -x .....
```

So everything that's listed from the base command in the terminal are things like $USER $LANG $HOME $SHELL, which can all be used to insert global variables into your script. For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /$HOME/newdir
touch /$HOME/newdir/newfile
```

The commands you entered would have different outputs reliant on whether or not you typed them into your terminal or ran from script. If you ran from script x would equal the last thing you assigned it to via "export" or locally assigning a value to it via "x=3".

> The script will hold the last assigned value until exit. "Export" will save the variable forever.

Comment: Environment variables are **not** global, they are copied to child processes (and that's the same on Linux ad Windows).  "*"Export" will save the variable forever.*" is very misleading, it won't save the variable forever, it will copy it to child processes.  Once they and the parent have gone, then the variable is gone.

Comment: The main differences between Windows and Linux/UNIX environment variables here is that on Windows they can be set from the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Environment and HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment) but on Linux/UNIX they can be set in various startup files (typically /etc/profile and $HOME/.profile, but there are more).  On both, programs can also set them themselves.

Comment: The Windows equivalent of `export` in `cmd.exe` is just to `set` a variable.  In `cmd.exe` all variables are environment variables.  Another difference is that on Windows environment variable names are not case sensitive but n Linux/UNIX they are.

Comment: I'm confused as to why SET xxx yyyy provides a different result then xx=yy and DOSKEY xx=yy if all variables are environmental variables. But, in WIN i'm normally a GUI baby anyway i suppose.

    ""Export" will save the variable forever." is very misleading
I was trying to avoid saying something like Export is a more non-volatile way of storing a variable, clearly I shouldn't have said that